# How can a div be aligned center using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

A div can be alinged center like this

```
<div align="center">Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Now, how can i achieve this using jquery.

In jquery we can work on css. But `align="center"` is not a css property.

SO how can we achieve this using jquery.

I want to mention that I wanted to know how to `align="center"` a div, not to just centering a div.

My question was just to apply the `align="center"` using jquery. The post which has been linked with this question of mine, has different approach using window.width and window.height method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 3 method for this:

Method 1 Using css Function of jquery:

```
$('div').css('text-align','center');
```

Method 2 Using attr Function of jquery: **attr stands for attribute**

```
$('div').attr('align','center');
```

Method 2 Using prop Function of jquery: **prop stands for property**

```
$('div').prop('align','center');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a property of div, you can use `.attr` or `.prop`,

Just doing this will work

```
$('div').attr('align','center');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/46/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
$('div').attr('align','center');
```

A better apporach for this would be using prop:

```
$('div').prop('align','center');
```

See [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this:

```
$('div').attr('align','center');
```

With [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

With Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute('align', 'center');
```

[javascript demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/eyxkv9c7/2/)

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/eyxkv9c7/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
$('div').prop('align','center');
```

As C-link Nepal mentioned, **.prop** is a better supported method for getting and/or applying attributes to elements.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sheldonbrax/ez2x5fao/)