# How to center an absolutely positioned element within its parent when the child element's height is unknown

Tags: html, css

In my layout, I am trying to output php generated items.
Each item retrieved from the database has a title, an image and a description.

I am trying to generate a layout that would have a thumbnail header composed of the img as a background  (with the css style border-radius: 50%) and the title as a banner centered in the middle and taking the whole width. But using top 50% on the absolutely positioned *div.title* centers via the top edge and the *div.title*'s height is dependent on font size.

I am wondering if there is a way to perfectly center the title, while keeping the border-radius effect considering that the only actual known dimension is the *div.item*'s width and all height data is ultimately determined by *.thumbnail-wrapper img* and *.title*'s font-size

the html is

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
      <img />
      <div class="title">Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.thumbnail-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-wrapper img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* this is the problem */
}
```

Thanks!

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FatalMojo/dcdt4ovs/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Comment: Are you open to using some Jquery and Javascript?

Comment: Why bring JQuery into the mix when CSS can handle the positioning just fine?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Moob, it doesn't work in my context because that would require taking the img out of the flow but the img is what give the thumbnail-wrapper its height. And since I do not know it's w/h ratio in advance, I cannot give the wrapper a preset height.  I could set the img as a background-image property but then I would lose the ability to apply the border-radius in the way I want.

Comment: And no, I'm looking for a scriptless solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS for centering an absolutely positioned element (i.e. add it to `div.title`):

```
/* centering css */
   top: 50%;
   left:50%;
   -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

[**Updated your JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/dcdt4ovs/2/)

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/2HLgZ/)

Comment: That's a great solution!  I can live with IE9- users seeing a slightly not centered title!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Only works in IE9+" is not strictly speaking true - it also works in Firefox, Chrome, etc. :) Both the solution and nthe wartning are nevertheless valid.