# How to make a jQuery plugin without selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How to make a jQuery plugin which needs some methods but doesn't need a selector like the following example?

```
$.plugin.method(param);
```

Comment: So for what pupose you want to develop a plugin, when you don't need a selector. You need a selector to apply your plugin.

Comment: Cause I use JQuery and its methods, so it's a jQuery plugin, In my opinion every jQuery plugin should be name jquery.plugin.js and uses $.

Comment: Okay! but yet you need to refer it with `this` keyword in this case.

Comment: that's my problem, it's easy to make $.plugin(); but about $.plugin.method(), mmm...

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/210733/1059101 shortest jquery plugin to center an element to the page.

Comment: It's in $(selector).plugin(); format, different from what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer,

```
// jQuery Plugin Syntax
(function ($) {
    $.plugin = {
        method: function(param) {
            alert(param);
        };
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Now you can call it this way:

```
$.plugin.method("Hello World!");
```