# How can I center the below form?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

How can I center the below form. Right now it is too far over to the right. I want it centered on the page (Moved slightly over to the left). I have tried a lot of different solutions however, I know I am missing something very small here. Thank you.

[image]

```
![<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Page | Contact</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/font.css'/>
<!-- CSS Files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/simple_menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/slider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/contact.css">

<!-- Contact Form -->
<link href="contact-form/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="contact-form/css/uniform.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact.js"></script>
<?php include 'common_header.php'; ?>

</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>
<div id="container">
  <div class="one-third"> &nbsp; </div>
  <div class="one-third">
    <div class="heading_bg">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    <form action="#" id="contact_form" class="TTWForm" method="post">
      <div id="field1-container" class="field f_100">
        <label class="required" for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
        <span id="name_validation" class="error_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="field2-container" class="field f_100">
        <label class="required" for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text">
        <span id="subject_validation" class="error_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="field5-container" class="field f_100">
        <label class="required" for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email">
        <span id="email_validation" class="error_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="field4-container" class="field f_100">
        <label class="required" for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <span id="message_validation" class="error_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="form-submit" class="field f_100 clearfix submit">
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit_button">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="one-third last">
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; height: 0px"></div>
</div>
<!-- close container -->
<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
</body>
</html>][2]
```

**CSS**

```
#after_submit, #email_validation, #name_validation {
    display:none;
}

#after_submit{
    background-color: #c0ffc0;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#after_submit{
    color: #6c6c6c;
}

.error {
  background-color:#FFDFDF;
  color:red;
}
.error_message{
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.row {
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant CSS to the form.

Comment: Why do you use `<div class="one-third">`, make 1 `div` which includes `form` and make its `marginLeft:auto` and `marginRight:auto`. So that `div` gets into center

Comment: If your class `.one-third` creates a column that is one-third of the `.container` parent block's width, is your form's width small enough to fit in the allocated space?

Comment: @dowomenfart Apologies for not posting the CSS. I thought I did. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only styling being done to the form? Seems like you're missing some CSS.

Comment: Should post the problem in a working fiddle, you're missing some css here for sure.

Comment: There is a center anything function i find it useful. Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/ee450g7p/  -- give it a go -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Comment: I'm not sure I like the `![` at the top.

Comment: Thank you everyone who commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
#contact_form{
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

[Check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/o0wxc9zc/)

I have not added all your CSS, only showed how you can center the form. Using the CSS above in your code, you would be able to center it.

You can put the form in a div and use css on the div or use for the form. Set width accordingly, but the margin-left and right when set to auto, put it into center of the screen, no matter what the screen size is.

If this doesnt work, then create a jsfiddle with all your relevant css and html and comment.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I adjusted the width etc accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Might have to play with the width and margin, but as long as they add up to 100%, you should be okay.

```
#contact_form, .heading_bg {
    display: block;
    position: relative
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 25%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That will at least center your main div. Then it's just a matter of playing with the inside div and input settings to get things where you'd like them.