# How to center an image using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script for my contact form, which is showing Thnks message and an image after customer pressed "Submit". The thing is that everything is aligned to the right, but I want to center it. Also,  it after the customer pressed "Submit" it pushes the next to it div down to the bottom. I will try to post the code and the link to my website.
[My website](http://web-artist.co.uk)

This is the code itself:

```js
//Contact form AJAX form
function _(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function submitForm() {
  _("mybtn").disabled = true;
  _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("n", _("n").value);
  formdata.append("e", _("e").value);
  formdata.append("p", _("p").value);
  formdata.append("m", _("m").value);
  formdata.append("plans", $('#my_form').find('input[name="plans"]:checked').val());
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("POST", "example_parser.php");
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      if (ajax.responseText == "success") {
        _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + '!</h2><p><img src="images/sent.png"></p>';
      } else {
        _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        _("mybtn").disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
//END
```

Btw, I use for styling Bootstrap. Sorry if it is not clear.

Comment: This sounds like something you would do with CSS rather than with jQuery?

Comment: I agree, this should be tagged differently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: `.contactus img {text-align: center;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Comment: My hosting doesn't update styles at the moment for some reason. I will come up with an answer either it is helpful or not after it will update my website. Thx guys!

Comment: I found the solution. Thx to every1 guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked your website contact form, it seems like you just need to add `text-align:center;` to class `.well-sm`

```
<style>
  .well-sm{text-align:center;}
</style>
```

This can be achieved with css only.

Comment: @AllinOne Glad to know, Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest this is probably best done with `CSS`:

This will do the trick:

```
.contactus {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you really want to use `jQuery` put this somewhere in your `document.ready` function:

```
$('.contactus').css('text-align', 'center');
```

Comment: Thx for help bro!