# How to center d3.js word cloud in container?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, word-cloud, d3-cloud

I'm displaying the word cloud inside a div container. But as you can see the `svg` is not centered.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? 
Here is my code (based on [Julien Renaux solution](https://julienrenaux.fr/2014/09/23/d3-js-responsive-word-cloud/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            #wordcloud {width: 1000px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid red}
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/d3-cloud/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tags.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wordcloud">

        </div>

        <script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20b();

var w = $('#wordcloud').innerWidth(), h = $('#wordcloud').innerHeight();

var svg_location = "#wordcloud";

var fontSize;

var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
        .timeInterval(Infinity)
        .size([w, h])
        .fontSize(function(d) {
            return fontSize(+d.value);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        })
        .on("end", draw);

var svg = d3.select(svg_location).append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

var vis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");

update();

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', update);
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', update);
}

function draw(data, bounds) {
    var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;

//   ***          
        svg.remove();
        svg = d3.select(svg_location).append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

        vis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");
//   ***   

    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

    scale = bounds ? Math.min(
            w / Math.abs(bounds[1].x - w / 2),
            w / Math.abs(bounds[0].x - w / 2),
            h / Math.abs(bounds[1].y - h / 2),
            h / Math.abs(bounds[0].y - h / 2)) / 2 : 1;

    var text = vis.selectAll("text")
            .data(data, function(d) {
                return d.text.toLowerCase();
            });
    text.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            });
    text.enter().append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            })
            .style("opacity", 1e-6)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .style("opacity", 1);
    text.style("font-family", function(d) {
        return d.font;
    })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return fill(d.text.toLowerCase());
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.text;
            });

    vis.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function update() {
    layout.font('impact').spiral('archimedean');
    fontSize = d3.scale['sqrt']().range([10, 100]);
    if (tags.length){
        fontSize.domain([+tags[tags.length - 1].value || 1, +tags[0].value]);
    }
    layout.stop().words(tags).start();
}

function changeWords(newTags) {
    tags = newTags;
    update();
}

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The statements 
var w = window.innerWidth,
    h = window.innerHeight;
in the draw method are resetting the w and h variables to the width and height of the entire window and not the width and height of the div wordcloud defined using the CSS #wordcloud {width: 1000px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid red}. That's why the word cloud is being drawn at the center of the screen and not the div.

If your objective is to have a responsive centered word cloud, you can ignore the div and the code snippet below should suffice. As you will resize the window you will see the word cloud resize and stay at the center of the window.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
      #wordcloud {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-cloud/1.2.5/d3.layout.cloud.js"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wordcloud"></div>

    <script>
      var fill = d3.scale.category20b();

      //   var w = $("#wordcloud").innerWidth(),
      //     h = $("#wordcloud").innerHeight();
      var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;

      var svg_location = "#wordcloud";

      var fontSize;

      var layout = d3.layout
        .cloud()
        .timeInterval(Infinity)
        .size([w, h])
        .fontSize(function(d) {
          return fontSize(+d.value);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        })
        .on("end", draw);

      var svg = d3
        .select(svg_location)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

      var vis = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");

      update();

      if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onresize", update);
      } else if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("resize", update);
      }

      function draw(data, bounds) {
        var w = window.innerWidth,
          h = window.innerHeight;

        $("#wordcloud").innerWidth = w;
        $("#wordcloud").index = h;
        //   ***
        svg.remove();
        svg = d3
          .select(svg_location)
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

        vis = svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");
        //   ***

        svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

        var scale = bounds
          ? Math.min(
              w / Math.abs(bounds[1].x - w / 2),
              w / Math.abs(bounds[0].x - w / 2),
              h / Math.abs(bounds[1].y - h / 2),
              h / Math.abs(bounds[0].y - h / 2)
            ) / 2
          : 1;

        var text = vis.selectAll("text").data(data, function(d) {
          return d.text.toLowerCase();
        });
        text
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
          .style("font-size", function(d) {
            return d.size + "px";
          });
        text
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
          .style("font-size", function(d) {
            return d.size + "px";
          })
          .style("opacity", 1e-6)
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style("opacity", 1);
        text
          .style("font-family", function(d) {
            return d.font;
          })
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return fill(d.text.toLowerCase());
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.text;
          });

        vis
          .transition()
          .attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")"
          );
      }

      function update() {
        layout.font("impact").spiral("archimedean");
        fontSize = d3.scale["sqrt"]().range([10, 100]);
        var tags = [
          { key: "Cat", value: 26 },
          { key: "fish", value: 19 },
          { key: "things", value: 18 },
          { key: "look", value: 16 },
          { key: "two", value: 15 },
          { key: "like", value: 14 },
          { key: "hat", value: 14 },
          { key: "Oh", value: 13 },
          { key: "mother", value: 12 },
          { key: "One", value: 12 },
          { key: "Now", value: 12 },
          { key: "Thing", value: 12 },
          { key: "house", value: 10 },
          { key: "fun", value: 9 },
          { key: "know", value: 9 },
          { key: "good", value: 9 },
          { key: "saw", value: 9 },
          { key: "bump", value: 8 },
          { key: "hold", value: 7 },
          { key: "fear", value: 6 },
          { key: "game", value: 6 },
          { key: "play", value: 6 },
          { key: "Sally", value: 6 },
          { key: "wet", value: 6 },
          { key: "little", value: 6 },
          { key: "box", value: 6 },
          { key: "came", value: 6 },
          { key: "away", value: 6 },
          { key: "sit", value: 5 },
          { key: "ran", value: 5 },
          { key: "big", value: 5 },
          { key: "something", value: 5 },
          { key: "put", value: 5 },
          { key: "fast", value: 5 },
          { key: "go", value: 5 },
          { key: "ball", value: 5 },
          { key: "pot", value: 5 },
          { key: "show", value: 4 },
          { key: "cup", value: 4 },
          { key: "get", value: 4 },
          { key: "cake", value: 4 },
          { key: "pick", value: 4 },
          { key: "went", value: 4 },
          { key: "toy", value: 4 },
          { key: "ship", value: 4 },
          { key: "net", value: 4 },
          { key: "tell", value: 4 },
          { key: "fan", value: 4 },
          { key: "wish", value: 4 },
          { key: "day", value: 4 },
          { key: "new", value: 4 },
          { key: "tricks", value: 4 },
          { key: "way", value: 4 },
          { key: "sat", value: 4 },
          { key: "books", value: 3 },
          { key: "hook", value: 3 },
          { key: "mess", value: 3 },
          { key: "kites", value: 3 },
          { key: "rake", value: 3 },
          { key: "red", value: 3 },
          { key: "shame", value: 3 },
          { key: "bit", value: 3 },
          { key: "hands", value: 3 },
          { key: "gown", value: 3 },
          { key: "call", value: 3 },
          { key: "cold", value: 3 },
          { key: "fall", value: 3 },
          { key: "milk", value: 3 },
          { key: "shook", value: 3 },
          { key: "tame", value: 2 },
          { key: "deep", value: 2 },
          { key: "Sank", value: 2 },
          { key: "head", value: 2 },
          { key: "back", value: 2 },
          { key: "fell", value: 2 },
          { key: "hop", value: 2 },
          { key: "shut", value: 2 },
          { key: "dish", value: 2 },
          { key: "trick", value: 2 },
          { key: "take", value: 2 },
          { key: "tip", value: 2 },
          { key: "top", value: 2 },
          { key: "see", value: 2 },
          { key: "let", value: 2 },
          { key: "shake", value: 2 },
          { key: "bad", value: 2 },
          { key: "another", value: 2 },
          { key: "come", value: 2 },
          { key: "fly", value: 2 },
          { key: "want", value: 2 },
          { key: "hall", value: 2 },
          { key: "wall", value: 2 },
          { key: "Thump", value: 2 },
          { key: "Make", value: 2 },
          { key: "lot", value: 2 },
          { key: "hear", value: 2 },
          { key: "find", value: 2 },
          { key: "lots", value: 2 },
          { key: "bet", value: 2 },
          { key: "dear", value: 2 },
          { key: "looked", value: 2 },
          { key: "gone", value: 2 },
          { key: "sun", value: 2 },
          { key: "asked", value: 1 },
          { key: "shine", value: 1 },
          { key: "mind", value: 1 },
          { key: "bite", value: 1 },
          { key: "step", value: 1 },
          { key: "mat", value: 1 },
          { key: "gave", value: 1 },
          { key: "pat", value: 1 },
          { key: "bent", value: 1 },
          { key: "funny", value: 1 },
          { key: "give", value: 1 },
          { key: "games", value: 1 },
          { key: "high", value: 1 },
          { key: "hit", value: 1 },
          { key: "run", value: 1 },
          { key: "stand", value: 1 },
          { key: "fox", value: 1 },
          { key: "man", value: 1 },
          { key: "string", value: 1 },
          { key: "kit", value: 1 },
          { key: "Mothers", value: 1 },
          { key: "tail", value: 1 },
          { key: "dots", value: 1 },
          { key: "pink", value: 1 },
          { key: "white", value: 1 },
          { key: "kite", value: 1 },
          { key: "bed", value: 1 },
          { key: "bumps", value: 1 },
          { key: "jumps", value: 1 },
          { key: "kicks", value: 1 },
          { key: "hops", value: 1 },
          { key: "thumps", value: 1 },
          { key: "kinds", value: 1 },
          { key: "book", value: 1 },
          { key: "home", value: 1 },
          { key: "wood", value: 1 },
          { key: "hand", value: 1 },
          { key: "near", value: 1 },
          { key: "Think", value: 1 },
          { key: "rid", value: 1 },
          { key: "made", value: 1 },
          { key: "jump", value: 1 },
          { key: "yet", value: 1 },
          { key: "PLOP", value: 1 },
          { key: "last", value: 1 },
          { key: "stop", value: 1 },
          { key: "pack", value: 1 },
          { key: "nothing", value: 1 },
          { key: "got", value: 1 },
          { key: "sad", value: 1 },
          { key: "kind", value: 1 },
          { key: "fishHe", value: 1 },
          { key: "sunny", value: 1 },
          { key: "Yes", value: 1 },
          { key: "bow", value: 1 },
          { key: "tall", value: 1 },
          { key: "always", value: 1 },
          { key: "playthings", value: 1 },
          { key: "picked", value: 1 },
          { key: "strings", value: 1 },
          { key: "Well", value: 1 },
          { key: "lit", value: 1 }
        ];
        if (tags.length) {
          fontSize.domain([+tags[tags.length - 1].value || 1, +tags[0].value]);
        }
        layout
          .stop()
          .words(tags)
          .start();
      }

      function changeWords(newTags) {
        tags = newTags;
        update();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Surabhi. But my objective is to get the cloud centered in a container of my choice not in the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen#answer-210733) is solving my problem.

I just had to add this piece of code:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
```

And use it at the end of the draw function: `$("svg").center(true);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
          #wordcloud {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
          }
```

with

```
            var w = window.innerWidth,
                h = window.innerHeight;
```